# Clicking/activating ActiveX control locks excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am encountering a small difficulty with an excel file I am working on. When moving from one sheet to another, the new activated sheet is sometimes locked in that sense that I can't make keyboard inputs. This seems to be the consequence of a interacting with a combobox or a listbox.

The issue also arises when I first click on the control and then try to change the content of the unlocked cell of the protected sheet. When the sheet is unprotected, the issue does not arise.

This seems to be resolved when I add this code on the control lostfocus event

```
debug.print selection.locked
```

Do ActiveX controls interfer with sheet protection or keyboard input (I can still use the dropdowns of those cell, select them with the mouse, etc.)
Any clue of how to resolve this without adding this mysterious line?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If it was a **protection** problem, an error message would appear.   Are you seeing an error message??

Comment: no error message: I just can't type in the cells but I can modify them through their dropdown menus. If I run some apparently unrelated code (like debug.print cell.locked) then i can type in those cells, even if i have not modified any property. That's strange to me...

Comment: it may not be a cell with data validation, but a form control, or activeX control combobox. i'm not super familiar with it, but try a right clic ont it , and see if at the bottom of the list you get a 'format control' wich sets its properties...

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding what you suggest but yes, I'm Actually using a combobox to go from one sheet to the other. although it seems independent because I have no issue with the combo, the problem lies in some cells not accepting changes through the keyboard. can you develop what you suggest? Would those controls "capture the keybord events"?

Comment: well, I put a if selection.locked=false then selection.locked=false in the lostfocus event of every activex and the problem does not arise anymore. strange thing...

Comment: ActiveX controls on worksheets have always been pretty buggy (random resizing etc). I suspect this is another such case. Use Forms controls if you can - they're usually more stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the formula bar hidden just turn it visible. I know it sounds wierd but it worked for me.